# Maximum cardinality

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $X$ be some set and $P$ be some subset of ${\frak P}(X)$. We can define the smallest cardinal $\frak k$ such that any $A \in P$ has cardinal $\leq \frak k$. Indeed we can consider the set of all cardinals of elements of $P$ and pick the supremum. On the other hand, it is not clear to me that we can define the smallest cardinal $\frak k$ such that any $A \in P$ has cardinal $< \frak k$ (strictly less). Is it possible indeed?

Comment: Using $\frak c$ for anything other than the continuum is just bad choice of notation. Use $\frak p$ instead.

Comment: If the sup is attained, pick the next one. If it is not attained, then the sup is the answer.

Comment: Changed $\mathfrak c$ to $\mathfrak k$; as Asaf indicated, it is bad practice to use common notation and assign a different arbitrary meaning to it.

Comment: The cardinal you want is the supremum of $\{|A|^+:A\in P\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of $\sf ZFC$ the cardinals are well-ordered. It suffices to show that there is a cardinal which is greater than any of the cardinals of the sets in $P$, in which case there is a least such cardinal.

Since $A\in P$ means $A\subseteq X$, this means that all those cardinals are strictly less than $|X|^+$. Therefore, there is a least cardinal $\kappa$ such that $|A|<\kappa$ for all $A\in P$.

Comment: I understand your answer but find it hard to believe. Could you tell me for example what is the smallest cardinal $\frak p$ such that $|\mathbf N|<\mathfrak{p}$?

Comment: timofei, that is the definition of $\aleph_1$. It is the least cardinal which is larger than $\aleph_0$, which itself is the cardinality of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Did you mean $|A| < \kappa$ rather than $|A| < \kappa^+$?  The OP wants the strict sup.

Comment: @Trevor: Oh yeah, thanks for catching that. I first posted an answer for $\leq$, then I read it again (minutes later, from my phone) and realized the mistake so I edited from my phone... and editing from an Android keyboard, as lofty as it may be... is no match for my idiopathic transient forgetfulness :-)

Comment: "idiopathic transient forgetfulness"... is that in the DSM? :-)

Comment: @Trevor: Well, I was going to ask them to put it in there... but I forgot. ;-)